# Jsonexception: text must begin with '{'

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

Hello Guys I am sending json object from javascript to servlet, But i am getting above exception

look at my javascript

```
<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var line = {
      lines: []
    };
    function changeColor( newColor,num) {
       line.lines.push({"linechange":num});
      var elem = document.getElementById(newColor);
      elem.style.background = "pink";

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "/SaveHighlights?p=" + line , true);
    }
```

Look at my servlet code

```
JSONObject jobj1 = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("p"));
Iterator it = jobj1.keys();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            int o = (int) jobj1.get(key);
            Syatem.out.println(key + o);
        }
```

Here is a sample json object i am sending

```
line = lines[{"linechange":2,
             "linechange":7,
              ......}];
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this

Stacktrace

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:188)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:314)
at SaveHighlights.doPost(SaveHighlights.java:25)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2516)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2505)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What ___exactly___ is the contents returned from `request.getParameter("p")`?

Comment: If your "JSON" starts with "line = lines[{ ..." then it is not JSON! That what the error message is telling you ...

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: "p" holds the variable line

Comment: @SumanthUdupa: I asked you for the _contents_ of that variable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON kindly read.

Comment: try both answers will give a total solution

Comment: @Cerbrus Hey I already posted the contents of variable line

Comment: What exactly is the contents __returned from__ `request.getParameter("p")`? You still have not answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
"/SaveHighlights?p=" + line
```

will result in

```
"/SaveHighlights?p=[object Object]"
```

because coercing an object to a string does that

you want (perhaps)

```
"/SaveHighlights?p=" + JSON.stringify(line)
```

edit:

based on the Java code, you may in fact want

```
"/SaveHighlights?p=" + JSON.stringify(line.lines)
```

> json object

no such animal ... JSON is a purely string data interchange format

as discussed in the comments, you're performing a POST with a querystring, while there may be some (semi valid) reasons to do so, either perform a GET or do the POST like this:

```
  function changeColor(newColor, num) {
      line.lines.push({
          "linechange": num
      });
      var elem = document.getElementById(newColor);
      elem.style.background = "pink";
      var params = 'p=' + JSON.stringify(line);
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "/SaveHighlights", true);
      http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
      http.send(params);
  }
```

You may need to make changes to the server side because you're no longer passing the data in the query string, I don't know enough about your server side to help with that

The string you'll be getting in parameter p on the server is likely to be something like

```
{
    "lines": [
      {"linechange": 3}, 
      {"linechange": 7}, 
      {"linechange": 5}
    ]
}
```

so, i think your code will try to "parse"

```
    [
      {"linechange": 3}, 
      {"linechange": 7}, 
      {"linechange": 5}
    ]
```

as an integer ... not 100% sure, as my java is rusty at best

Comment: Better would be to suggest not using a query string with a _POST_.

Comment: I just realized that when I saw this answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried as you specified but now i am getting below error.                   Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: yeah, you'll need to show exactly what the data you're sending is ... the snippet in your question is unlikely to be exactly what you are getting ... the more accurate information you can supply, the easier it is for people to help ...

Comment: I am sending integer values by putting it in key "linechange". After that at server side i am retrieving back my integer values.

Comment: I've updated the answer - I think you are mistaken in what you think the data you are getting is

Comment: An easy fix would be to `JSON.stringify(line.lines)` instead of `JSON.stringify(line)`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should not use JSONObject. You have to use JSONArray since that is what you are trying to do in the code.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.getEntity(String.class));
        for(int i =0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){
            if(jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject){
                JSONObject jsnObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
                String finalValue = (String)jsnObj.get("id");
            }
        }
```

JSON Object follows the following Structure:

```
{
 "array": [
{
    key: "value",
    key: "value"
},
{
    key: "value",
    key: "value"
}

]
}
```

JSON Array follows the following Structure:

```
[
 { "key":"value" , "key":"value" }, 
 { "key":"value" , "key":"value" }, 
 { "key":"value" , "key": "value" }
]
```